# AVAudoPlayerNode to play a sound for a defined number of times

Tags: swift, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

Is it possible in AVAudioPlayerNode to loop an audio sound for a number of times only instead of infinite times? The below code scheduled the audio for an infinite number of times instead of saying 5 times.

```
aVAudioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(buffer!, at: nil, options: AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferOptions.loops, completionHandler: nil)
```

I am looking similar as AVAudioPlayer's as **numberOfLoops** to define how many times to play an audio. I could use AVAudioPlayer but there is no functionality to play with audio pitch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheduleBuffer documentation says "Schedules the buffer to be played following any previously scheduled commands.".  So just schedule it multiple times.

```
extension AVAudioPlayerNode {
    func sceduleBuffer(_ buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, numberOfLoops: Int = 1) {
        for _ in 0..<numberOfLoops { scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil) }
    }
}
```